# How to write a DB2 select query to include the string before the '-' delimiter

Tags: sql, db2, substring

I have a column "Department" in my Table "College". Department is having data like

```
Commerce1-683877
Science2-678900
```

I need to write a select query which returns only Commerce1 and Science2.

I am completely new to DB2, please help me solve this.

```
select substring(department,0,CHARINDEX('-',department) as DEPT from College
```

Edit -1 : Thanks @Charles

I tried your solution :
`select  substring(department , 1, LOCATE('-',department) - 1) AS DEPT from College`

but it's throwing me an error :

`SQL Error [42815]: THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF ARGUMENT 3 OF SUBSTRING IS INVALID. SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, DRIVER=4.9.78`

Edit 2: You're right @Charles, all my rows doesn't contain '-'
I tried using the below query as well but getting the same error :

```
select substring(department,1, LOCATE('-',department || '-') - 1) as DEPT from College
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform and version of Db2?

Did you look for an appropriate Db2 SQL Reference manual?

Note Db2 SQL string & arrays start at 1, not 0.

`select substring(department,1, LOCATE('-',department) - 1) as DEPT from College`

Comment: Thanks @Charles , I am using DB2 z/OS. Please have a look at my edit once

Comment: sounds like not all your rows have a '-'

Comment: Yes. I tried with || operator but it didn't work, giving same error

Comment: It worked for me, I used substr with the same query. Thanks @Charles

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `regexp_substr()`:

```
regexp_substr(department, '^[^-]+')
```